# Merge branch 'X' into 'Y', where 'X' already has a reverted merge commit of 'Y'

Tags: git

Alright, so we mistakenly merged 'Y' into 'X' and pushed. Since this was a mistake we reverted that commit. All good

Now i want to merge latest changes from 'X' into 'Y', but git is showing a bunch of files are removed that shouldnt be. They were removed from branch 'X' in the revert commit, but should still exist on 'Y'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverting a merge has a consequence that's almost always unintended: git effectively interprets it to mean that the branch changes will *never* be needed.  The problem is that git sees

```
O --- x --- x --- M --- W --- x --- x <--(master)
 \               /
  A ---- B ---- C --- D --- E <--(branch)
```

where `W` "undoes" the changes introduced to `master` by `M`.  If you now merge `branch` into `master`, the merge base is `C`; that is, git thinks `A` thru `C` are already accounted for in `master` by `M` so it doesn't think it needs to go back to `O` for a merge base.

So while there are many reasons a `revert` might be the best solution, it can require some extra work down the road.

The simplest procedure is to revert `W` on `master` and then merge `branch`.

```
O --- x --- x --- M - W - x - x - M' - M2 <--(master)
 \               /                    /
  A ---- B ---- C ------- D -------- E <--(branch)
```

What I don't like about this is that there's a pretty good chance `M'` will be in a broken state, which could interfere with future bug-hunting (e.g. if you use `bisect`).  Some people also just think it looks "ugly", though I don't put a lot of weight on that concern personally.

It may seem like you just want to "squash" `M'` and `M2` together, reproducing the merge you thought you were going to get.  This may seam aesthetically pleasing, but it creates an "evil merge" - a merge whose patch relative to its parents is not what would be assumed.  Plus it's just not that easy to do (though by no means impossible).

The other practical option is to create one or more new commits that reintroduce the changes originally introduced by `A` through `E`, basically getting git to "forget" that the changes are "accounted for".

```
git rebase -f O branch
```

(Note that you can't use `master` as the upstream here; you have to specify that the upstream is commit `O`, probably by giving it's SHA ID.)

```
  A' --- B' --- C' --- D' --- E' <--(branch)
 /
O --- x --- x --- M --- W --- x --- x <--(master)
 \               /
  A ---- B ---- C
```

From here a simple merge of `branch` into `master` will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You should revert the reversion and merge X into Y. Now it might be an issue if you don't want to revert in X. In that case create a new branch from X (say Z), perform the revert on Z and merge Z into Y.